# Problems with MySQL Query (SELECT)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, rows

I have this columns:

"uid, street, reg_number, ecc.."

I need to test it by running this query:

```
SELECT street FROM dict WHERE uid = '1001' AND reg_number = '243222';
```

But every time I run the query including reg_number in the WHERE clause the count of affected rows remains at 0, why is that?

The value in the reg_number column is correct but still does not work..

Comment: Your query should do what you want. Please provide a minimum reproducible example (sample data and desired results, as tabular text).

Comment: I think a factor causing this would be your data type for each column. Try checking it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because no rows are affected. The SELECT statement does not affect rows, it returns them.

Try the following queries, one by one in Workbench.

```
SELECT street FROM dict; 

SELECT street FROM dict WHERE reg_number = '243222';

SELECT street FROM dict WHERE uid = '1001';
```

If your values are correct, and street has a value, you will get row(s) back.

If that doesn't work at all, try these:

```
SELECT * FROM dict; 

SELECT * FROM dict WHERE reg_number = '243222';

SELECT * FROM dict WHERE uid = '1001';
```

This will help you use the process of elimination to figure out what isn't right.

If they are working in Workbench, but not your software, you are reading the row data incorrectly from the query, or the handle for the query was unset (failed). Knowing what language and what code you are using would be helpful.

One more thing -- if this data was entered by hand or is stored in VARCHAR and not some other numerical storage type, never underestimate the power of an invisible trailing space (at the end); in that case, try this:

```
SELECT street FROM dict WHERE TRIM(uid) = '1001' AND TRIM(reg_number) = '243222';
```